# Insert values from variable and DataFrame into another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

On start I have two DataFrames and one variable:

```
id=1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2], 'col0': [3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [13, 14, 15],'col2': [23, 24, 25]})
```

I have to map **id** variable and the corresponding **col0** cell from **df1** DataFrame to all rows in **df2** DataFrame. I tryed and as the result I made the code below:

```
df2.insert(0, "id", id)
df2.insert(1, "col0", df1[df1['id']==id]['col0'])
```

It seems to me that the code should work correctly, but unfortunatelly I have a **NaN** value in the **col0** column.

```
   id  col0  col1  col2
0   1   3.0    13    23
1   1   NaN    14    24
2   1   NaN    15    25
```

The expected result was:

```
   id  col0  col1  col2
0   1   3.0    13    23
1   1   3.0    14    24
2   1   3.0    15    25
```

I've spent over an hour and can't figure out why I'm getting this kind of result. If possible, could you, please:

1. explain briefly why I am getting the error
2. fix my mistake in the code

Comment: could you please try filling or deleting those NAN values.

Comment: is the problem that 3 should be filled in for the `NaN`'s? Could you please post the expected result?

Comment: @Uttam i can, operators 
    df2.at[1,'col0']=3
    df2.at[2,'col0']=3
fill and work correctly NaN values and work correctly

Comment: @rhug123yes, that is the problem..

Comment: @rhug123 regarding the expected result, I fixed the initial message

Comment: awesome. Hopefully my answer helps you out.

Comment: @Ivan7 Please let me know following answer helps

Comment: BIG THANKS for everybody, @rhug123 , I expessially appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Have a good Week-end!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is on this string `df1[df1['id']==id]['col0']` when you use this, it returns a Series type. Yes it just have a value, but is still a Series with just one value.

To solve this issue is very very very simple, you just have to call the first item at the Series object like this: `df1[df1['id']==id]['col0'][0]`

Your code with the ajustment must look like this

```
import pandas as pd

id=1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2], 'col0': [3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [13, 14, 15],'col2': [23, 24, 25]})

df2.insert(0, "id", id)
df2.insert(1, "col0", df1[df1['id']==id]['col0'][0])

print(df2)
```

Then your new df2 is like this:

```
   id  col0  col1  col2
0   1     3    13    23
1   1     3    14    24
2   1     3    15    25
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `df1[df1['id']==id]['col0']` returns a series with one index value.

```
0    3
Name: col0, dtype: int64
```

When you insert this, it is matching `index 0` in your original `df`, and therefore not filling in all the values.

In order to get 3 to fill for all values, try adding `.to_numpy()[0]` to the end of `df1[df1['id']==id]['col0']`. This will return just `3` without the index, and should return no `NaN` values.

Comment: @ rhug123 I am sorry but it seems to me that df2.insert (1, "col0", df1 [df1 ['id'] == id] ['col0']. to_numpy [0]) does not work for me - I get an error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'. I have upgraded pandas (pip install --upgrade pandas) but I still get this error

Comment: @ rhug123 could you, please, comment?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason seems `df1[df1['id'] == id]['col0']` is of type **Series** with only one element (**3**), so it populates the first row with it and rest comes out as **NaN**.
But if you make the code as follows then you will get the expected result.

```
import pandas as pd

id=1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2], 'col0': [3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [13, 14, 15],'col2': [23, 24, 25]})
print(df2.head(5))
df2.insert(0, "id", id)
col_ = df1[df1['id'] == id]['col0']
df2.insert(1, "col0", col_[0])
print(df2.head(5))
```

Please let me know if it helps
[image]